# How do you model multiple arrival distributions?

Tags: python, resources, distribution, yield, simpy

Python:

I am simulating a call-centre with 2 types of incoming calls: Sales calls, and service calls.

These calls have different, independent distributions, which enter the same system.

I have function, arrivals which contains:

```
iat_sales = random.expovariate(1/3) 
yield env.timeout(iat_sales)
```

I want to incorporate:

```
iat_service = random.triangular(0,0,6) 
yield env.timeout(iat_service)
```

how can I yield each event simultaneously?

---

This is the solution I have come up with:

```
def arrival_list():
    
    sales_time = 0           #sim time of sales arrival
    service_time = 0           #sim time of service arrival
    sales_list=[]           #list of sequential sales arrivals [arrival time,'sales']
    service_list=[]         #list of sequential sales arrivals [arrival time,'service']
    arrivals = []      #ordered list of arrivals (sales and service merged) [arrival time,arrival type,iat]
    
    while sales_time < sim_end:
        iat_sales = random.expovariate(sales_rate)                    
        
        sales_time += iat_sales
        
        sales=[sales_time,'sales']
        sales_list.append(sales)
        
    while service_time < sim_end:
        iat_service = random.triangular(0,6,0)        #### 
        
        service_time += iat_service

        service=[service_time,'service']
        service_list.append(service)
        
    arrivals = sales_list + service_list
    arrivals.sort()
    arrivals[0].append(arrivals[0][0])
    
    for i in range(len(arrivals)-1):
        arrivals[i+1].append(arrivals[i+1][0]-arrivals[i][0])
    
    return arrivals
```

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, a simple implementation can be done like this, where a simulation is run indefinitely with 1 second intervals and calls are considered to arrive if their random values exceed some thresholds:

```
import random
import time

def generate_calls():
    return random.expovariate(1/3), random.triangular(10, 20, 5)

def simulation(count, sales_acceptance, services_acceptance):
    # run the simulation indefinitely
    while True:
        print('Time: {}'.format(count))
        sales_call, services_call = generate_calls()
        
        # calls arrive if the values exceed some thresholds
        if sales_call > sales_acceptance:
            print('Sales call arrived!')
        if services_call > services_acceptance:
            print('Services call arrived!')
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1

simulation(1, 2, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have three separate parallel processes.
1- One process for making Sales calls.
2- One process for making service calls.
3- One process for handling calls.

```
import simpy 
import random

sim_end = 1000;

def generateSalesCall(env, call_pipe):
    while env.now < sim_end:
        # put call in the pipe
        yield call_pipe.put("sales");
        interval = random.expovariate(1/3);
        yield env.timeout(interval);

def generateServiceCall(env, call_pipe):
    while env.now < sim_end:
        # put call in the pipe
        yield call_pipe.put("service");
        interval = random.triangular(0,6,0);
        yield env.timeout(interval);

def handleCalls(env, call_pipe):
    while(True):
        call = yield call_pipe.get();
        if call == "sales":
              print(env.now, "sales call");
        elif call == "service":
              print(env.now, "service call");

env = simpy.Environment();
call_pipe = simpy.Store(env);
env.process(generateSalesCall(env, call_pipe));
env.process(generateServiceCall(env, call_pipe));
env.process(handleCalls(env, call_pipe));
env.run();
```